# Loading multiple external properties files from spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to load all the properties files with `Spring` from an external folder. I successfully load one file but adding a wildcard to the mix does not seem to work.

This works (load **test.properties**):

```xml
<bean id="propertiesLocation"
    class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextParameterFactoryBean">
    <property name="initParamName"><value>file://EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY/test.properties</value></property>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" ref="propertiesLocation"></property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

This does not (load ***.properties**):

```xml
<bean id="propertiesLocation"
    class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextParameterFactoryBean">
    <property name="initParamName"><value>file://EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY/*.properties</value></property>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" ref="propertiesLocation"></property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

The error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY/*.properties (No es un directorio)
```

How can I make Spring load all the external properties files in a folder?

**Edit**: I use the first bean (**ServletContextParameterFactoryBean**) because in the project I retrieve the path from the `web.xml` file. I forgot about this and just pasted the path in the bean, it is incorrect but has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: do you really have a root `/EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY`?

Comment: checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924912/multiple-properties-files-in-spring-3-0

Comment: i dont have the '/EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY' folder, it is just an example.

Comment: Thanks @jozzy, but unfortunately the wildcard doesn't work for me with external property files, just with classpath files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use following:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="file://EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY/*.properties"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

If you need include more resources you can do next:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" >
        <list>
            <value>classpath:single.properties"</value>
            <value>file://EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY/*.properties"</value>
            <value>file://ANOTHER_EXTERNAL_DIRECTORY/*.properties"</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

With default implementation of `PropertyEditor`, Spring will convert strings into `Resource`. You can find [details in documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-as-dependencies).

Hope this will be helpful.