# Spring how to load multiple property files in one bean

Tags: java, spring

I have a applicationContext that loads a properties file and a bean that is injected as a resource.  This works correctly.

```
<bean id="testSettings" class="com.icat.di.testing.framework.TestSettings" scope="singleton"/>
<util:properties id="testProperties" location="classpath:${test.properties}" />
```

I would like to add a second properties file.  I've read that multiple `<util:properties` entries are not allowed.

I tried the older method of adding a list of properties:

```
<bean id="testSettings" class="testing.framework.TestSettings">
    <property name="testProperties">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:test.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="configProperties">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I added configProperties as a resource in my TestSettings class.  This fails to load the application context.

How do you load two properties files in Spring 4?

Comment: I think this question was answered a time ago on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924912/multiple-properties-files-in-spring-3-0.

Comment: Turns out you can have multiple <util:properties .../>.  I had some other conflicting changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this property in your bean:

```
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
```