# Can I use Spring's util:properties and context:property-placeholder together?

Tags: spring, xml-configuration

I have the following config in a spring applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="file:///absolute/path/to/foo.properties"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="file:///absolute/path/to/bar.properties"/>
    <util:properties id="baz" location="file:///absolute/path/to/bar.properties"/>
```

I can put debug breakpoints where the property files are loaded and see the property files' values are indeed loaded.

But in my bean, `@Value("#{baz.myProp}")` is resolved whereas `@Value("${myProp}")` blows up in `PropertyPlaceholderHelper`, as `PropertySourcesPropertyResolver` can't find `myProp`:

```
DEBUG [...] - Searching for key 'myProp' in [environmentProperties]
DEBUG [...] - Searching for key 'myProp' in [systemProperties]
DEBUG [...] - Searching for key 'myProp' in [systemEnvironment]
DEBUG [...] - Could not find key 'myProp' in any property source. Returning [null]
DEBUG [...] - Searching for key 'myProp' in [localProperties]
DEBUG [...] - Could not find key 'myProp' in any property source. Returning [null]
```

Why is that and how can I make it work (using the `$` property placeholder resolution, instead of the  `#` SpEL syntax)?

Do the properties loaded via `context:property-placeholder` get discarded/overwritten by `util:properties` (which is only accessible via the `baz` reference)?

Answer (score 0):

[Turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22303436/2018047) this is all that needs to go on each of the `context:property-placeholder` lines to give each one a chance to take part in resolving the property: `ignore-unresolvable="true"`...

Comment: Don't (as you will probably miss important exceptions). Use a single `property-placeholder` with a comma separated list of locations.